# Is a MySQL JOIN with LIMIT optimized internally?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

A table `community` as `id: int, name: varchar`. Another table `category_people` as `community_id: int, person_id: int`. A JOIN with LIMIT query could be

```
SELECT b.user_id, group_concat(a.name SEPARATOR ',') as groups
FROM communities a
JOIN communities_users b
ON a.id = b.community_id
GROUP BY b.user_id
LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 2000;
```

In this query, will MySQL perform any internal optimizations and (a) do the limit,offset part first and join later or (b) perform a join on full table and then fetch the limit, offset window?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the MySQL 5.6 Manual on [LIMIT Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html), it appears to be (a):

"As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client, it aborts the query unless you are using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS."

Comment: Cool. Although limit with offset will increase the row scan linerarly.